# Windows batch file to login to Putty saved ssh session and respond to series of prompts

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssh, windows-10, putty

Everyday I have to manually login to an ssh session through Putty and select specific options in order to run a program that sends out an email (about an hour later). I want to automate this with a batch program that can be run daily using Windows Task Manager but am not very experienced with these types of scripts. Is this possible to make work?

Here is what I have tried:

I have two batch files - myscript.bat and start_input.bat. I want to automatically execute start_input.bat to run the full program and have the email sent from the remote server I'm logging into.

myscript.bat

```
cd C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
plink "offsite_server"
```

start_input.bat

```
(echo.&echo myusername&echo mypassword&echo c&echo f&echo o&echo c&echo y&echo  &echo q&echo q&echo q&echo q) | myscript.bat
```

When I do this manually I login to the session on Putty and then enter a series of inputs to complete the process:
press return
type "username", press enter
type "password", press enter
type "c"
type "f"
type "o"
type "c"
type "y"
press space bar
type "q"
type "q"
type "q"
type "q"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Windows Task Manager alone can't handle this level of automation. Batch files are also not inherently part of the Windows Task Manager, but can be scheduled to run using it. If the primary aim is to automate a PuTTY login, `plink` really offers a more straightforward method. You could create a batch file like this:

login.bat

```
C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe -ssh offsite_server -l myusername -pw mypassword -m C:\path\to\commands.txt
```

The sequence of commands you mentioned seems tied to the server's own interface rather than to PuTTY, so this may not work. A static batch script may not suffice for this. For a more dynamic solution, you could either use a Python script or VBScript to automate the keystrokes. Assuming you want to keep the built-in steadiness of Windows, VBScript, although poorer, may suffice.

script.vbs

```vb
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

' Run Putty and connect to the server
objShell.Run "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe -ssh offsite_server -l myusername -pw mypassword"

' Wait for Putty to launch
WScript.Sleep 5000

' Send your sequence of commands
objShell.SendKeys "c{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 100
objShell.SendKeys "f{ENTER}"
' ... (continue for the rest of your commands)

' Close Putty
objShell.SendKeys "%{F4}"
```

Python, with its robust libraries, can handle SSH connections effectively, while also offering a more versatile environment for what you are asking. The paramiko package is especially useful for this:

```py
import paramiko

# Initialize SSH client
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the server
ssh.connect('offsite_server', username='myusername', password='mypassword')

# Run commands
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('c; f; o; c; y; q; q; q; q')

# Close connection
ssh.close()
```

You can schedule any of these scripts to run automatically using the Windows Task Scheduler. Keep in mind that these are basic examples and may require further adaptation based on your server and network setup, as the problem is entirely there.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What your VBS script does can be done in batch file too (not that I object to your Python solution). And the `ssh.exec_command('c; f; o; c; y; q; q; q; q')` does not seem to be at all what the OP needs. So I do not think you have really answered OP's question.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Allow me to clarify some distinctions. The `ObjShell.SendKeys` method in VBS emulates keyboard strokes, allowing a degree of interaction with an already-running program that **can't** be replicated with simple CMD batch commands. It doesn't merely send text; it simulates the usual keyboard actions.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl As for the use of `ssh.exec_command` in Python, I agree it may not precisely suit the OP's needs. Nevertheless, the intent wat to provide a foundational example for automation using Python, like a pseudocode. The script may require user-specific modifications depending on their unique server configuration, something I noted in my original answer. As for my understanding, this may help. If you have suggestions, I can edit the answer if appropriate. Happy to help.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl for greater clarification, the VBS `ObjShell.SendKeys` allows for a more interactive way of automating tasks that require keyboard input, which can be particularly useful for interacting with GUI or running applications where simple text-based command-line input wouldn't suffice. An already running program can't get inputs from CMD in the "arguments" way.

Comment: Ok, I didn't notice that you actually run PuTTY, not Plink. There it makes difference (it won't with Plink). On the other hand, automating a GUI application from a non-interactive Task Scheduler Windows session seems like a gross hack to me (if it won't at all).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It's what they asked for. That's why I suggested both VBS and Python - offering flexibility for OP. It works. As it's a GUI, there is nothing to do except direct connection, like with python, or this GUI hack with VBS.